# Поставить флаг true false при отправке данных

Tags: php

Подскажите как написать условие, чтобы при установке true false, если ложь то данные не уходили в базу.
Код отправки данных в БД:

```
$site = trim(strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
      $city = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['city']));
      $name = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']));
      $text = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['text']));
 
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        define('DB_USER', '******');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', '*******');
        define('DB_NAME', '******'); 
 
        define('DB_CHARSET','utf8');
        define('DB_COLLATION','utf8_general_ci'); 
 
        $db  = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
        mysqli_set_charset($db, DB_CHARSET) or die(mysqli_error($db)); 
        
        
        $city_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $city);
        $name_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name);
        $text_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $text);
        $site_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $site);
        $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO `responses` (`city`, `name`, `text`, `site`, `time_created`) 
        VALUES('{$city_sql}', '{$name_sql}', '{$text_sql}', '{$site_sql}', '{$created}')";
 
        mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я осмелюсь предположить, что это будет примерно вот так...

```
$SendToBaseAccept = false; // в начале кода
if ($SendToBaseAccept == true) {
    // здесь код отправки (то, что хотите отправить, если true)
}
```

Comment: не находите, что `== true` здесь излишне?

Comment: @teran и почему же?

Comment: наверное потому что `if($x == true)` то же самое что просто `if($x)` и вдобавок при нормальном наименовании переменных более читаемо?

Comment: @teran результат при этом одинаков, Вы затрагиваете тему эстетики кода. В таком случае можно использовать и ```$x == true ? $y : $z;```